# Mockito and expected the exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

I create test from my Controller and it must return the redirecting url to "/register/duplicate". But when I perform that, I get exceptions, like DataIntegrityViolationException. The controller should catch this exception, but does not catch

How it's works? And what I can do, to the controller an exception has occurred and executes code in "catch" cause, will be redirecting to /register/duplicate

Test:

```
@Test
public void testRegisterPageLogic_Duplicate() throws Exception {
    expectedUser = new User("Jorg", "Brush");
    UserService mockService = mock(UserService.class);

    userService.add(expectedUser);

    when(mockService.add(expectedUser)).thenCallRealMethod();

    registerController = new RegisterController(mockService);
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(registerController).build();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/register")
            .param("hide", "up")
            .param("username", expectedUser.getUsername())
            .param("password", expectedUser.getPassword()))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/register/duplicate"));

    Mockito.verify(mockService, atLeastOnce()).add(expectedUser);

    userService.remove(userService.findUser("Jorg").getUserId());
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public String register(@RequestParam("hide") String hide,
                       @RequestParam("username") String username,
                       @RequestParam("password") String password) {

    if (hide.equals("up")) {
        try {
            userService.add(new User(username, password));
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            return "redirect:/register/duplicate";
        }
    }
    User user = userService.findUser(username);
    if (user == null) {
        return "redirect:/register/notExists";
    }
    UserSession.setUser(user);
    UserSession.setId(user.getUserId());
    return "redirect:/notes/" + UserSession.getUser().getUsername();
}
```

Comment: I have read your question twice, and sorry I don't understand what you want

Comment: are you asking how to use mockito to make some mock throw an exception??

Comment: Even I could not get the question.

Comment: @RC. yes, some likes that. I want, when perform method `userService.add()`, was throw exception, and it catch this exception in the catch case `catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to simplify, if the code is:

```
try {
    userService.add(new User(username, password));
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    return "redirect:/register/NOT-OK";
}
return "redirect:/register/OK";
```

And you want to test **both** branches, then

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // for @Mock
class TheTest {

    @Mock
    UserService mockService;

    MockMvc mockMvc;    

    @Before
    public void setup() {        
        RegisterController registerController = new RegisterController(mockService);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(registerController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOK() throw Exception {
        // mockService does nothing by default

        mockMvc.perform(post("/register"))
               .andExpect(view().name("/register/OK"));

        Mockito.verify(mockService).add(Matchers.any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotOk() {
        Mockito.when(mockService.add(Matchers.any(User.class))
               .thenThrow(new DataIntegrityViolationException()); // adjust DataIntegrityViolationException constructor args if required.

        // now mockService throw a DataIntegrityViolationException when mockService#add(User) is called

        mockMvc.perform(post("/register"))
               .andExpect(view().name("/register/NOT-OK"));

        Mockito.verify(mockService).add(Matchers.any(User.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: because `new User()` gives you a brand new user everytime

Answer (score 0):

To raise exception in Mockito, you don't need to call real method. You can use this code:

```
when(mockService.add(expectedUser)).thenThrow(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
```

Comment: I tried it, but differently, new DataIntegrityViolationException(""). But when perform this method `mockService.add(expectedUser)`, in controller, this try{}catch is ignored and continues to run. Then, I catch an error in test: Expected: /register/duplicate Actual: /register/notExists